# How to make `ls` color its output by default, without setting up an alias?

Tags: linux, ls, xterm

I don't want an alias (`alias ls='ls --color'`), and I had previously set this up on Mac OSX using `CLICOLOR` environment variable which magically brought colors to `ls`. Now I am on Linux (Arch x86-64) with `xterm` and a really basic setup, and I can't make `ls` output color (using `ls` verbatim). I **do** get color when using `--color` switch.

Is there no way to achieve this without an alias? POSIX compliance would be nice :-)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

There is no way: the ls man page will show you that the default setting (for --color) is 'none' - ie. never use colour.

Any reason you don't want to use aliases? I'm a recovering Red Hat user, so every time I install a new distribution I set three ls aliases like so:

```
## Colorize the ls output ##
alias ls='ls --color=auto'

## Use a long listing format ##
alias ll='ls -la'

## Show hidden files ##
alias l.='ls -d .* --color=auto'
```

Comment: No reason I cannot - I was on Mac OSX the other day, and it supported the `CLICOLOR` which I thought was kind of standard (you always tend to think that these things are standard). And I also always thought of aliases as more of an retrofit solution. But they'll do just fine :-)

Comment: On Mac OSX you can use `alias ls='ls -G'`

Comment: also add `alias grep='grep --color'` to it ;)

Comment: Put them together like so `alias ll='ls -la --color=auto'`

Comment: A reason not to use aliases is that they are not always available. When shelling out from ruby or python, or when running a remote command over ssh, your aliases will be ignored and only the bare `/bin/ls` will run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the alias method so that every time you open the terminal and use `ls` (verbatim just `ls` , not `ls --color`), results will be coloured. You can add the alias to your `.bashrc`, for example, as the following command line:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

Comment: Thank you, but I explicitly mentioned in the question: "I don't want an alias". Also, I am satisfied with the current accepted answer, although nothing would prevent you from adding another one, obviously, aliases or not.

Answer (score -5):

if using the -F option --color is unnecessary, for instance `alias ll='ls -alF' shows colors`

Comment: This is incorrect.

Comment: One can use `\ls -alF` to test the original ls command and not be confused with an option set elsewhere.